# Add jQuery results for form

Tags: jquery

I am having an issue trying to add several variables together.  The variables are results from other formulas and do not display as a form element.  The code below is just a snippet of the whole program:

```
//card 1 interest
$('#card_bal_1, #card_int_1').keyup(function() {
    var card_mon_int_1 = parseInt($("#card_bal_1").val()) * ((parseInt($("#card_int_1").val()) / (12)) * (.01));
    if (!isNaN(card_mon_int_1)) {
        $("#card_mon_int_result_1").html(card_mon_int_1); //floor or round
    }
});

//card 2 interest
$('#card_bal_2, #card_int_2').keyup(function() {
    var card_mon_int_2 = parseInt($("#card_bal_2").val()) * ((parseInt($("#card_int_2").val()) / (12)) * (.01));
    if (!isNaN(card_mon_int_2)) {
        $("#card_mon_int_result_2").html(card_mon_int_2); //floor or round
    }
});


//total interest paid
$('#card_mon_int_result_1, #card_mon_int_result_2').keyup(function() {
    var total_card_monthly_interest = parseInt($("#card_mon_int_result_1").val()) + parseInt($("#card_mon_int_result_2").val());
    if (!isNaN(total_card_monthly_interest)) {
        $("#total_monthly_interest").html(total_card_monthly_interest); //floor or round
    }
});​
```

The HTML is basically:

```
<span id="card_mon_int_result_1"></span>
<span id="card_mon_int_result_2"></span>
<span id="total_monthly_interest"></span>
```

This is just one example of trying to get this to work.  I understand the results of the interest of card 1 and card 2 are not not form elements.  So my problem is converting card 1 and card 2 interest paid into variable so then to add them together.

Any suggestions are greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

I changed a code, working example : [example](http://jsfiddle.net/AFgeD/7/)

card_mon_int_result_1 and card_mon_int_result_2 is not form fields, you can't use keyup() and val().